# Вставить bbcode и поставить курсор в место для ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery.fn.extend({
        insertAtCaret: function(myValue){
            return this.each(function(i) {
                if (document.selection) {
                    //For browsers like Internet Explorer
                    this.focus();
                    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
                    sel.text = myValue;
                    this.focus();
                }
                else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
                    //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
                    var startPos = this.selectionStart;
                    var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
                    var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
                    this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos)+myValue+this.value.substring(endPos,this.value.length);
                    this.focus();
                    this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
                    this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
                    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                } else {
                    this.value += myValue;
                    this.focus();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.bb_code_paste', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();  
        $('[name="text"]').insertAtCaret($(this).data('value'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Введите сообщение" name="text"></textarea>

<br>

<a href="#" data-value="[b][/b]" class="btn bb_code_paste btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><b>Жырный</b></a>
<a href="#" data-value="[i][/i]" class="btn bb_code_paste btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i>Курсив</i></a>
<a href="#" data-value="[s][/s]" class="btn bb_code_paste btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><s>Зачеркнутый</s></a>
<a href="#" data-value="[u][/u]" class="btn bb_code_paste btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><u>Подчеркнутый</u></a>
<a href="#" data-value="[url][/url]" class="btn bb_code_paste btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Ссылка</a>
```

У меня получилось вставить bbcode в текстовое поле в то место где находится сам курсор. Но как мне после вставки поместить курсор между двумя тэгами? то есть `[i]$c$[/i]` надо чтобы `$с$` исчезло а на его место стал сам курсор.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.bb_code_paste', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  
  $('[name="text"]').insertAtCaret($(this).data('value'));
  var pos = $('[name="text"]').prop("selectionStart");
  var bbLength = $(this).data('value').length;          
  $('[name="text"]').prop("selectionStart", pos - bbLength / 2)
    .prop("selectionEnd", pos - bbLength / 2);
});
```